# Undo Subversion commit in NetBeans

Tags: svn, netbeans

I want to undo the latest commit in my Subversion in NetBeans. I have found out, that I could somehow do that with a "svn merge HEAD:oldrev", but I am confused by the "Merge changes" NetBeans dialog. Where do I have to enter the old revision? Can someone help with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the revert function. Then you enter the revision that equals HEAD-1. This will return the repo to the given revision (the one before your commit, in this case).

The line command should be " svn merge -rHEAD:your revision" or you can try "svn commit -m".